# bootstrap-table event ontoggle doesn't work

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, toggle, bootstrap-table

I need to do something when state of the `ontoggle` button is changed. my code is:

```
$('#table').bootstrapTable({
'onToggle': function (arg1) {
        // ...
 $('body').css("color","red");
}
});
```

but it isn't working. 
I had tried this code too

```
$('#table').on('toggle.bs.table', function (number,size) {
$('body').css("color","red");
});
```

but this too isn't working.
and When I use other event,  then all is ok.
Could you help me? thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes around onToggle:

```
onToggle: function (arg1) {
    // ...
    $('body').css("color","red");
}
```